# VS Code debug <optimized out> with Flutter 3.10 / Dart 3.0

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

After latest "flutter upgrade" I'm having problems viewing some variables during debug in VS Code.

How can I view the contents of variables when hovering instead of getting this

Screenshot of hovering variable:
[image: 1]

This only happens to some variables, others I can view the contents of as normal.

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-SE)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at
      /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.0/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (5 days ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    34.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/niklaselelid/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 34.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) •
    • ios
    • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64 • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

I have looked for possible settings to configure the behavior. Without luck.

Comment: another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76268121/11107541. possibly related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125289

Comment: can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: [also related](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52430)

Answer (score 21):

Nothing wrong with your code. There's [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52430) with Dart SDK, which is not resolved yet. Please upvote it to get more attention from the Dart team.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Dart 3.0. It's tracked in [Cannot debug values inside some if-statements: [sentinel kind: OptimizedOut] from evaluateInFrame()
#52430](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52430).

The fix has been made in [commit `f5080be`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/f5080bedb38c77bd99b5caa0bc012007ab7158e3). The fix was announced [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52430#issuecomment-1631602949) by a-siva:

> This fix should be in Dart 3.1 Beta 3/ Flutter 3.13 (beta channel) which is slated for release on July 12th 2023 and would make it into the stable release channel on 16 August 2023

However, the fix actually failed to make it into Flutter 3.13 / Dart 3.1. Flutter 3.13.4 uses Dart 3.1.2, which the fix didn't make it into. So if you're using Flutter you'd either need to upgrade Flutter to something newer than that which includes Dart 3.2.0 (Flutter 3.16 will release on 2023 Nov 15th with the fix ([source](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53654#issuecomment-1760449810))), or ask the maintainers [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53654#issuecomment-1756016916) to cherry-pick the fix into a stable Flutter release, which looks like has been done in [[CP] [stable] Request cherry pick of commit f5080bedb38c77bd99b5caa0bc012007ab7158e3 into stable #53747](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53747) and which has now been implemented by [commit `1ce0cc8`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/1ce0cc8bd0a43d8c253e3d2ac109bb1eb441b6b7).